# Numerical integration VS Discretion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter, linear-control

If I want to develope a control system for a microcontroller. What is the best/recommended way to control?

1. Numerical integration e.g for-loop - Continuous time with digital controller

> ```
> n = 1000; % Loops
> x = [0; 0];
> for i = 1:n
>   tic;
>   dx = A*x + B*u;
>   u = -L*x + r
>   dt = toc;
>   x = x + dx*dt;
>   t = t + dt;
> endfor
> ```

2. Discretion e.g transform a state space model to discrete model.

$$F = e^{Ah}$$
$$G = \int_{0}^{h}e^{At}Bdt $$

$$ x(k+1) = Fx(k) + Gu(k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with microcontrollers myself, but I will try to compare the two using the knowledge I do have. Both can probably be made to work if the sampling rate would be significantly higher then your bandwidth. But since the sampling rate is usually also used to generate the control input $u$, with zero order hold in between the sample times. Therefore I would say that the discretized state space model would be preferred. For this I would have to assume a (near) constant sample rate. It can also be noted that [discretizing the continues time model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Discretization_of_linear_state_space_models) can also be done with

$$
e^{\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}h} = \begin{bmatrix}F&G\\0&I\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the real continues time model implementation I would assume that you would not calculate the states directly yourself, but use an observer, which calculates the full state space from the outputs of the system. The integrated continues time model should be more flexible in variable sample rates. However it might be good to look into different numerical integration methods, because (forward) Euler's method might [perform badly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Numerical_stability).

When using the discretized model, then you can make use of the theory for discrete Kalman filters. This can give you an estimate of the state before the beginning of a new sample time, so you can calculate a full state feedback control input without a delay.

Comment: I would take that as a "Yes, it's possible to create a controller by using a Continuous time model". I also take your answer as "There is some benefits of discrete models too". I was trying the method you shown, but it didin't work.  Thank you.

Comment: I will look more at the discrete time feedback. A microcontroller can do delays very easy.

Comment: But I still can calculate a full state feedback control input without a delay by using continuous model too.

Comment: Wait! There is also Kalman filters in continuous time too.

Comment: In this case. I have a PLC who run every 100 ms and meanwile every sample, the PLC collects all analog data from the sensors. That means I can use a continuous time model? Right? Just make so the observer updates the estimated states?

Comment: What do you mean by "run every 100 ms" and "collects all analog data from the sensors"? The PLC gets one sample of the analog sensor every 100 ms? Or do you mean that the PLC can only change the input to the system every 100 ms, but collects the sensor data much faster, or something entirely different?

Comment: Let's say that they are two programs at the PLC. One who control the output and one who reads the input. The input reads every 10 ms and the output will be controlled every 100 ms. So i can get 10 samples and create a mean by 10 before I giving that to the controller. But I don't see and reason to have a discrete model when I can use algoritms to compute the next estimated and integrated states for a continuous model?